# Symfony 2 test xml with Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler

Tags: php, xml, unit-testing, symfony, domcrawler

I've got an url that return an xml but I have some problem to extract "link" element.

```
<rss xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <item>
      <id>123</id>
      <title>my title</title>
      <link>
        http://example.org
      </link>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

I need to test it with

```
Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler
```

These are my tests:

```
$crawler = $this->client->get('/my-feed');

$items = $crawler->filterXPath('//channel/item');
$this->assertGreaterThanOrEqual(1, $items->count()); // ok pass

// ...
$titles = $items->filterXPath('//title')->extract(array('_text'));
$this->assertContains("my title", $titles);  // ok pass


// ...
$links = $items->filterXPath('//link')->extract(array('_text'));
$this->assertContains("example.org", $links);  // KO!!! don't pass

var_dump($links); // empty string
```

"link" is a reserved word?

Comment: Could you check out what ``$items->filterXPath('//link')`` contains?

Comment: it return a crowler object:


`code
object(Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler)#1968 (5) {
  ["uri":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["defaultNamespacePrefix":"Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler":private]=>
  string(7) "default"
  ["namespaces":"Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler":private]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["baseHref":"Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler":private]=>
  NULL
  ["storage":"SplObjectStorage":private]=>
  array(1) {
    ["0000000049a37b5b000000002da5082f"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["obj"]=>
      object(DOMElement)#1970 (0) {
      }
      ["inf"]=>
      NULL
    }
  }
}`

Comment: your RSS xml code is broken

Answer (score 2):

Your XML is broken:

1. you don't have a closing channel node `</channel>`
2. you don't have a closing rss node `</rss>`

Here is corrected XML :

```
<rss xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <item>
            <id>123</id>
            <title>my title</title>
            <link>http://example.org</link>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

Then, `->extract()` returns *An array of extracted values*. So you shouldn't directly try to see its contain but get the first element and do your test:

```
$this->assertContains("my title", $titles[0]);
// ...
$this->assertContains("example.org", $links[0]);
```

Comment: Yes, sorry I was wrong in copy paste code, Xml is correct with 

<channel/> and </rss>

Problem is only in $items->filterXPath('//link') other elements works

Comment: @Vega I've tried with the xml I posted and using `[0]` and it worked for me.. Are you sure about your xml? What does `$this->client->getResponse()->getContent()` says after your `->get(`?

Comment: @Vega Glad to hear that! You can now accept the answer :)